# Get Servlet Output Stream in ZK

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, zk

In case of Servlets we have,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
    resp.getOuputStream().write(somthing);
    }
```

the above gives servlet output stream is there any way in ZK to do the same.

Comment: ZK is a web application framework which uses ajax technology.
[Home Page](http://www.zkoss.org/) [Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZK_(framework))

Comment: @Ramesh: Put your mouse above the `[zk]` tag below the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your real use-case for this ?

If you are writing some details in html , 
it's better to use zk component directly.

In some case you could get the response from the execution.

```
((HttpServletResponse)Executions.getCurrent().getNativeResponse()).getOutputStream()
```

But I don't think that's a good idea, be sure you know what you are exactly doing before you use this approach.

It's better to provide your use-case instead of code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

*I found this solution, using ZK components:*

```
 Clients.evalJavaScript("window.open('http://www.google.com','','top=100,left=200,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1,resizable=1')");
```

[ZK-opens-new-window](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/26qv3sl/2-ZK-opens-new-window#source-2)